# How to check if a directory exists in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I would like to translate this Linux/Bash script to Windows shell:

```
if test -d myDirName; then echo "ok"; else mkdir myDirName; fi
```

It tests if a directory exists, and if it doesn't it creates it.

Comment: The actual linux/bash command would simply be: `mkdir -p myDirName`. After spending days trying to translate relatively simple bash-scripts into batch-sh*t (assigning the result of a function to a variable?), I've decided to just make people install cygwin.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
@echo off
IF exist myDirName ( echo myDirName exists ) ELSE ( mkdir myDirName && echo myDirName created)
```

**Added by Barlop**

While the above works for this particular situation, the title says about testing specifically for a directory. Phogg's comment using `if exist mydirname\` rather than `if exist mydirname` is the way. Some answers have used \nul but \nul is problematic in NT.  Not including a trailing backslash will test for a file or a directory. So, for a directory, include the trailing backslash.

Comment: This is correct for testing file existence, but how do you know that it's a directory? The simplest answer is `if exist mydirname\ ` and the rest as you say. Alternately, you could actually get a `test` binary and use it on Windows.

Comment: @phogg: In the context of this specific question: if it exists but is a file, you *still* cannot `mkdir` it.

Comment: @grawity: If it exists but is a file the script will probably fail later when trying to use it as a directory, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: how can i check if not exist?

Comment: @sunglim by writing `  If not exist myDirName\  `  similarly `if not 1==1 echo hmm`   or if exist myDirName\ ELSE blahblahblah

Comment: Verifying it's a directory is apparently "a bit" more compicated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033801/checking-if-a-folder-exists-using-a-bat-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666225/how-to-test-if-a-path-is-a-file-or-directory-in-windows-batch-file/ for details and solutions.

Answer (score 23):

Here is what I just found out:

You can test if a nul file exists; if the directory exists it will contain a nul file, if the nul file does not exist then the directory does not exist.

```
IF exist myDirName/nul ( echo myDirName exists ) ELSE ( mkdir myDirName && echo myDirName created)
```

Comment: +1 - this works in all Windows and MS-DOS versions, unlike plain `if exist dirname` which appears to be specific to Windows NT.

Comment: that's wAS a stupid code compare to linux mkdir -p myDirName :p

Comment: It should be a backslash, not a forward slash.

Comment: @grawity What do you think of this though, apparently some issue with doing \nul? http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4913

Comment: @barlop: I think that cmd.exe is one of the worst scripting languages in existence, and that one should use PowerShell or other alternatives if at all possible. As for `\nul`, it is not necessary in Windows NT anymore, plain `if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)"` should work (unless you're still targetting Windows 98...)

Comment: @KitHo: You are comparing different pieces of code. Linux `mkdir -p myDirName` is equivalent to Windows `mkdir myDirName`, without any extra options. However, they _don't do the same thing_ as dev008's example does.

Answer (score 14):

Use a backslash, not forward slash: `myDirName\nul` not `myDirName/nul`

```
md foo 
echo.>bar 
for %I in (foo bar xyz) do @( 
  if exist %I ( 
    if exist %I\nul ( 
      echo -- %I is a directory 
    ) else ( 
      echo -- %I is a file 
    ) 
  ) else ( 
    echo -- %I does not exist 
  ) 
)
```

-- foo is a directory
-- bar is a file
-- xyz does not exist

edit: this only works if directory name does not contain spaces

Answer (score 7):

Some have suggested doing \nul, but that doesn't seem to work reliably in NT

```
C:\blah>md abc

C:\blah>if exist abc\nul echo yes
yes

C:\blah>if exist "abc\nul" echo yes

C:\blah>
```

http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4913

```
foxidrive writes-

The trick with nul worked in pre NT versions of windows.

Now you would use this, with a trailing backslash.

if exist "C:\abcde\" echo the folder exists
```

Re the question

```
C:\blah>if exist "abcd\" (echo yes) else (echo no && mkdir abcd)
no

C:\blah>if exist "abcd\" (echo yes) else (echo no && mkdir abcd)
yes

C:\blah>
```

Answer (score 4):

I wondered why joe had a downvote as I was experiencing the same kind of problem on Windows 7, namely that

IF EXIST filename\NUL

was returning TRUE for both files and directories.
I found an alternative solution at [www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_ifexistfolder.php](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_ifexistfolder.php) and came up with a revised version of DVF's FOR loop:

```
FOR %I in (foo bar xyz) DO @( PUSHD %I && (POPD & echo -- %I is a directory) || ( IF exist %I ( echo -- %I is a file ) ELSE ( echo -- %I does not exist ) ) )
```

Comment: That was the only solution that worked, thanks.
 
I added a "2>NUL" to avoid the error message and changed the echo values to 1 (directory exists), 0 (directory does not exist), -1 (a file with the same name exists)
 
FOR %A IN ("C:\temp\foo\HELLO WORLD5") DO @(PUSHD "%A" 2>NUL && (POPD & ECHO 1) || (IF EXIST %A (ECHO -1) ELSE (ECHO 0

Comment: (sorry, I didn't manage to format the code as code in the reply although I tried so many things :-( until editing the comment timeouted after 5 mins :-( )

Answer (score 2):

I see many have problems with differentiating between files and folders. Has anyone tried to simply cd into it after checking it exists? Then cd will either succeed or fail.

```
set MyDir = "MyTestDir"
IF exist MyDir (
    cd MyDir 
    IF ERRORLEVEL NEQ 0 (
        echo "Error: %MyDir% already exists, but it is a file!"
        exit 1
    ) else (
        # Do not forget to cd back
        cd ..
    )
) else (
   # Did not exist yet, so create it.
   mkdir MyDir
)
```

Comment: (1) If you’re going to use a variable, use the variable. All occurrences of `MyDir` after the first line should be `%MyDir%`. (2) The `cd ..` won’t do what you want if  `%MyDir%` is a multi-level pathname (e.g., `Pictures\cats`) or even an absolute pathname (e.g., `\Windows`). Consider using `pushd`/`popd` and/or `setlocal`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to test the directory exists *only when its a valid directory*.

```
set myDirName=foobitybarbitybaz
dir /A:D %myDirName% >nul 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (@mkdir %myDirName%) else (@echo "ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exist myDirName/nul
```

also is true if myDirName is a file, whis is not the searched functionality

Comment: `C:\blah>touch abe<ENTER>C:\blah>if exist abe\nul echo err<ENTER>
C:\blah>if exist abe/nul echo err<ENTER>C:\blah>` i'm no fan of \nul in NT but it isn't. You should have given some output.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using **`dir /d | findstr \[\.\.\]`**:

```bat
2>nul dir /d "myDirName" | findstr \[\.\.\] >nul && echo= "ok" || mkDir myDirName&&echo= Is NOT dir


2>nul dir /d "myDirName" | findstr \[\.\.\] >nul && echo= "ok" || mkDir myDirName
```

---

For create if exist or not and for ignore error...

```bat
2>nul mkDir myDirName
```

Also ...

```bat
if exist "myDirName\." (echo/"ok") else mkdir myDirName

rem :: or direct create myDirName hidden/ignoring error
       2>nul mkdir myDirName & if exist "myDirName\." echo/ exist 
rem :: output: exist
```

Answer (score -1):

Finding a folder shouldn't be this difficult.  My solution, use perl:

```
for($cnt=$#ARGV; $cnt>=0; --$cnt)
{
   if ( -d "$ARGV[$cnt]" ) { 
      print "argv[$cnt]=$ARGV[$cnt] is a folder\n";
      $dir = $ARGV[$cnt];
      break;
   } else {
      print "argv[$cnt]=$ARGV[$cnt] is Not a folder\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not get it