# Where to get binaries for linux command "test" on windows

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

I've got a simple command I'd like to run in windows cmd:

```
//returns "file not found" for directories and "file exists" for files
test -f file/path/here && echo file exists || echo file not found
```

I've searched SO and found this Q&A: [How to check if a directory exists in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/219050/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-windows)

the first comment in the accepted answer suggests that you can install binary files for it on windows machines. I've done this before with `curl` binary, but I haven't found `test` binary file. Is there some repository for such files? Where should I search. Google is unfortunately vague, because well, commands name is `test` :)

I am extremely uncomfortable with with cmd, so if you can write an alternative, I'd take it.

Note, I am aware of cygwin, but I'd like to keep this simple and in cmd.

Comment: One thing that's not clear: Why do you need a linux binary on Windows? Why not just do it the Windows way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4340395/712526

Comment: Concerning your original question, I'd say [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) is a good bet. Under the install folder, under `/usr/bin`, I have a `test.exe`, which works in cmd. You can also use [`pacman`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-arch-linux-package-management) ([originally](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks) from [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman)) to install other packages, and it might not require opening the MSYS shell.

Comment: @jpaugh this will also return true for folders. And i am terrible with batch scripting

Comment: and you were spot on with msys2. feel free to post it as an answer

Comment: Incidentially, if you prefer the Linux shell, you can use MSYS for most day-to-day tasks. It does a pretty good job of emulating a Linux shell environment, using MinGW (i.e. Windows) executables.

Comment: May be I didn't get something, but if you talking about cmd, then ugly windows shell aka CMD can do what you want by simply using `IF` statement like `IF EXIST somefile ( ECHO Yes exist )` or opposite `IF NOT EXIST somefile ( ECHO Not exist )`  More on this here: https://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: @Alex if exists also returns true for folders. I would need some nested if statements, that I am horrified to do with cmd :)

Comment: Ohh, I feel your pain... When `cmd` come on scene I hopped `command.com` absurdity would gone away but it isn't happened. BTW, if you don't want 3rd party dependency on MSYS you can use new bloated way with PowerShell by utilizing `Test-Path` cmdlet like https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880042 or use VBS function FileExist (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22388077)

Comment: I don't remember, was WSL already a thing in 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/) is a good bet. Under the install folder (in my case, `C:\msys64`), under `usr\bin`, I have a test.exe, which works in cmd.

You can also use [pacman](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-arch-linux-package-management) ([originally](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks) from [Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman)) to install other packages, and it might not require opening the MSYS shell.